# How do you use fonts after installing xna

Tags: fonts, xna

I've downloaded a tutorial that had fonts included in the source.  When I try to build the project, I always get the following error message:

> Error 1   The font family "Joystick"
>   could not be found. Please ensure the
>   requested font is installed, and is a
>   TrueType or OpenType font.

The font was added via the control panel, and is a TrueType font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see the Font in the Windows\Fonts directory? If the font is installed, it should be there. Have you try to use this font in Word or other program to see if it's really installed?

You might contact the person who is the source code is coming and ask him the question, or you could try to use his source code and just change the font.

Comment: It is in the directory, as you can see I've added it through the control panel, and yes I can use the font in notepad, I have made the program compile using Arial and Comic Sans MS, so I'll send the creator an email.

Comment: I Downloaded a test font Proggy and it worked so I guess it was the font file after all

Answer (score 0):

Just Restart your editor once. It works. Because the editor loads the fonts only in the beginning.