# Is it true, visual studio can't handle fonts installed after it was?

Tags: visual-studio, fonts

I was trying to solve my [XNA Font problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254718/how-do-you-use-fonts-after-installing-xna), when I found this [here](http://www.xnaresources.com/pages.asp?pageid=33):

> Visual Studio doesn’t recognize any
>   fonts you add after it is up and
>   running.

Is there a way to use fonts installed after Visual Studio?

After finding out that is was the Font file why would the tutorial mention something like that ?

Comment: I tried: restarting IDE, restarting virtual PC, should I try repair?

Comment: You are in Virtual PC? Is there any other detail that you forget to say:P ?

Comment: Not really, if I change the font Name to Arial, Comic Sans MS it compiles

Comment: You asked an almost identical question yesterday.  SO isn't a BBS or message-board system!

Comment: While searching for an answer to the first one, an other came up ... I agree that they are related in a certain way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have successfully installed a [PROGGY](http://www.proggyfonts.com/index.php?menu=download) font.  It was usable after I restarted VC6.

I suspect they are talking about restarting your visual studio, instead of reinstalling your visual studio.

Comment: I used the Proggy font it worked, never second guessed the font used with the tutorial source ...

Comment: There might be an additional restriction that only fixed with fonts can be seen.

Comment: Emphasizing _after_. I could see the font while VS was still running but had to _restart_ it to display it.

Answer (score 3):

I've had issues with VS recognizing fonts that were installed while VS was open. Restarting VS and the machine didn't resolve the issue. The fix was closing VS, uninstalling the fonts, then re-installing them while VS was not running.

Answer (score 2):

You should close Visual Studio and open it again. If it doesn't work, than you might need to uninstall the font (if from a program) and install it once Visual Studio is closed. But, I doubt this is necessary, maybe rebooting your machine in the last resort but closing VS and opening it again should do the job,

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine this is only true until you restart the IDE. Easy enough to test, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install the Source Code Pro font, and found that Visual Studio would only display TTF fonts in the dropdown. I had been installing the ODF version and spent a lot of time restarting the computer and Visual Studio in various combinations. Finally I tried the TTF and it was instantly recognized.